# Android alarm never cancels after some particular end time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have set the start time and end time of my alarm as below:

```
Calendar startalarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
startalarmTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
startalarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
startalarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
startalarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar endalarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();<br>
endalarmTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
endalarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
endalarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31); 
endalarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

int repeatingInterval = 5;   //5 seconds 
long endTime = endalarmTime.getTimeInMillis();
long startTime = startalarmTime.getTimeInMillis();
```

I'm setting the repeating alarm as below:

```
Intent broadCast = new Intent(ctx,AlarmBroadCaster.class);
broadCast.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 12345, broadCast, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
AlarmManager alrmMgr =  (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alrmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startTime,repeatInterval*1000, pIntent);
```

The alarm rings well at 11:30 and repeats for every 5 seconds which is fine.

To cancel the alarm at 11:31 I have written the following piece of code in onReceive() of my BroadCastReceiver as below:

```
public void onReceive(){ 

 if(System.currentTimeMillis()==alarmEndTime){ 
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Cancelled Endtime",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<receiver android:name="com.andr.broadcastreceiverdemo.AlarmBroadCaster"></receiver>
```

The Alarm never cancels when it reaches end time . 
Can any one help me how to cancel the alarm when it reaches some time .

Comment: Did you add the receiver in manifest? What action is the receiver looking for?

Comment: My receiver in manifest is as below:                                     <receiver 
            android:name="com.andr.broadcastreceiverdemo.AlarmBroadCaster"
            ></receiver>

Answer (score 0):

Change it to 
if(System.currentTimeMillis()>alarmEndTime) to stop as soon as the system time exceeds the alarm end time. == checks if its exactly equals and misses most of the time.

Comment: It worked . But the Alarm does not cancels .The program control flow comes into the "if" condition , but Alarm does not cancel

Comment: I have one more doubt. Though I cancel the Alarm, the control comes repeatedly to onReceive() method of BoradcastReceiver.Is it desired scenario. Will the broadcast receiver receives call to OnReceive() though Alarm is cancelled.